# How do you mimic the infinite scroll on Instagram with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, instagram

I've written a small Python program to scrape Instagram profiles to extract data and display various stats. I am able to gather data from the first 9 photos on a profile (or however many appear on initial load), but I haven't been able to load the additional photos (due to the infinite scroll mechanism). I have read online about web scraping with infinite scrolling and people have said that you need to replicate the request made to load additional images. I've been unable to replicate the request so far, is anyone able to help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to write all the code again, there are a lot of libraries already written which replicate all the requests.

One such library is `https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api`

Solution using this library,

```
from instagram_private_api import Client, ClientCompatPatch

user_name = 'YOUR_USERNAME'
password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
username_to_scrape = 'USERNAME_TO_SCRAPE'

all_posts = []

api = Client(user_name, password)
posts = api.username_feed(username_to_scrape)  #Gets the first 12 posts
# Extract the value *next_max_id* from the above response, this is needed to load the next 12 posts

next_max_id = posts["next_max_id"] 

all_posts = all_posts + posts

# 
next_page_posts = api.username_feed(track_username, max_id = next_max_id)
```

This is just a quick example to help you get started.

**Update: Saving & Loading Cookies**

```
#Saving cookies
cookies = api.cookie_jar.dump()
with open("cookies.pkl", "wb") as save_cookies:
    save_cookies.write(cookies)

#Loading cookies
with open("cookies.pkl", "rb") as read_cookies:
    cookies = read_cookies.read()

#Pass cookies to Client to resume session
api = Client(user_name, password, cookie = cookies)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. Just out of interest, the author mentions that you should cache the session to prevent being blocked by Instagram. Do you know how to do this, or where I can find this documentaion

Comment: @liamw9 Just updated the answer on how to save and load the session. Can you also accept the answer?